# Openerp - Multi Company consolidated P&L and Balance Sheet

Tags: odoo, account, consolidation

I am using Openerp version 7.0 and using "Indian Accounting template " to configure accounts for three companies.
1.ABC Solutions(Parent)
2.ABC Solutions Hyderabad(children of ABC Solutions)
3.ABC Solutions Delhi (ABC Solutions)
ABC Solutions Don't have any transactions, only ABC Solutions Delhi, ABC Solutions Hyderabad have transactions.
I need consolidated p&L and Balance sheet for ABC solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you change chart of account  based on chat of account it will generate company based if you have any doubt check below

```
<record id="account_common_report_view" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">Common Report</field>
                <field name="model">account.common.report</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Report Options" version="7.0">
                    <label string=""/>  <!-- binding for inherited views -->
                    <group col="4">
                       <field name="chart_account_id" widget='selection' on_change="onchange_chart_id(chart_account_id, context)"/>
                       <field name="company_id" invisible="1"/>
                       <field name="fiscalyear_id" domain="[('company_id','=',company_id)]"/>
                       <field name="target_move"/>
                    </group>
                    <notebook tabpos="up" colspan="4">
                        <page string="Filters" name="filters">
                            <group>
                                <field name="filter" on_change="onchange_filter(filter, fiscalyear_id)"/>
                            </group>
                            <group string="Dates"  attrs="{'invisible':[('filter', '!=', 'filter_date')], 'required':[('filter', '=', 'filter_date')]}">
                                <field name="date_from" />
                                <field name="date_to" />
                            </group>
                            <group string="Periods" attrs="{'invisible':[('filter','!=','filter_period')], 'required':[('filter', '=', 'filter_period')]}">
                                <field name="period_from" domain="[('fiscalyear_id', '=', fiscalyear_id)]"/>
                                <field name="period_to" domain="[('fiscalyear_id', '=', fiscalyear_id)]"/>
                            </group>
                        </page>
                        <page string="Journals" name="journal_ids">
                            <field name="journal_ids"/>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="check_report" string="Print" type="object" default_focus="1" class="oe_highlight"/>
                        or 
                        <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel" />
                    </footer>
                </form>
                </field>
            </record>
```

The Above is common for accounting reports which can be found in account/wizard/account_report_common_view.xml

Inherit and Make company_id as visible to filter company based reports also do query changes in account.common.report if needed

Comment: Is it not possible with configuration changes in accounts of main company ?.